# Consuming cURL in restful codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

In native PHP, I have a consuming restful server like this:

```
$url = "http://localhost/pln/api/json?rayon=$rayon&id_pel=$id_pel&nama=$nama";

$client = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$respone = curl_exec($client);

$result = json_decode($respone);
```

How can I access cURL like this when using CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 2):

There's no active cURL library around for CodeIgniter 3.x. There were [one for CI 2.x](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl) which is no longer maintained.

Consider using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) which is very popular and considered as a de-facto HTTP interfacing library for PHP. Here's an usage example from the docs:

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// "200"
echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// {"type":"User"...'
```

I also recommend using [Requests](http://requests.ryanmccue.info) which is inspired by [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module and is way more easier than Guzzle to get started with:

```php
$headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
$options = array('auth' => array('user', 'pass'));
$request = Requests::get('https://api.github.com/gists', $headers, $options);

var_dump($request->status_code);
// int(200)

var_dump($request->headers['content-type']);
// string(31) "application/json; charset=utf-8"

var_dump($request->body);
// string(26891) "[...]"
```

As [CodeIgniter 3.x has support for Composer](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) packages out of the box, you can easily install one of these packages through composer and start using it right away.

I stongly recommend you to not to go down the *"Download Script"* way as suggested in [Manthan Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40189307/65732). Composer provides PHP with a sophisticated dependency management ecosystem; Utilize that! "Download This Script" dog days are over for good.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following function in codeigniter for curl url and works fine, try it out:

```
function request($auth, $url, $http_method = NULL, $data = NULL) {
//check to see if we have curl installed on the server 
        if (!extension_loaded('curl')) {
//no curl
            throw new Exception('The cURL extension is required', 0);
        }

//init the curl request
//via endpoint to curl
        $req = curl_init($url);
//set request headers
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth,
            'Accept: application/xml',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ));

//set other curl options        
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);


//set http method
//default to GET if data is null
//default to POST if data is not null
        if (is_null($http_method)) {
            if (is_null($data)) {
                $http_method = 'GET';
            } else {
                $http_method = 'POST';
            }
        }

//set http method in curl
        curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method);

//make sure incoming payload is good to go, set it
        if (!is_null($data)) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $raw = http_build_query($data);
            } else {
//Incase of raw xml
                $raw = $data;
            }
            curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $raw);

        }

//execute curl request
        $raw = curl_exec($req);


        if (false === $raw) { //make sure we got something back
            throw new Exception(curl_error($req) . $url, -curl_errno($req));
        }

//decode the result
        $res = json_decode($raw);
        if (is_null($res)) { //make sure the result is good to go
            throw new Exception('Unexpected response format' . $url, 0);
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You could use default Curl library of codeigniter:

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$result = $this->curl->simple_get('http://example.com/');
var_dump($result);
```

For more details refer this link :
https://www.formget.com/curl-library-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @sepehr answer. Requests library can be configured in a very easy way in codeigniter as described here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46062566/2472685